# How Do I Share to Facebook With Custom Text

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a task to add links to a web page to enable the user to post a short message to Facebook.  There may be multiple messages on the page, each with its own link.  The intent is to launch a Facebook share dialog pre-populated with the text of the message which the user can then modify, accept and/or reject.

I'm pretty new to programming anything for Facebook.  I'm fairly confused and am not sure what to ask first, so I'll go with a very basic question:  what's the simplest way to do this?  I gather from Facebook's documentation that I probably have to use the Javascript SDK and/or the Open Graph technology.  Is this correct, or is there another option I'm missing?  Is there a really clear example of this kind of solution anywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: you should read the documentation.

Comment: You are not allowed to pre-fill the message of any share/post, see https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#control, 2.3, and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill

Comment: Thanks; it seems I misunderstood the interface a little.  It's not the message itself I need to populate, but the description.  Which presents other problems, but that needs to be a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a facebook app first so you have your app_id and app_secret.
After that you need to request permissions to the user to publish_actions. If the user accepts, you'll receive a token (you need to store it in db). If you need to publish actions in a user page instead of his own page, you also need the manage_pages permission.
You need to read the facebook graph api documentation to understand how all this works.
The access token you receive expires after certain time. So, when you receive it, you can ask for a long lived token. The page tokens doesn't expire.
Facebook evaluates your app before approving it to be in production. They ask a couple of questions about how you'll use the user's token and data. You might have to put pictures of the flow too.
As far as I know, Facebook won't allow you to send pre populated messages to the user's wall. They user has to write it.
Hope it helped a bit!

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like I may have been asking the wrong question.  Back to the drawing board.